# How to deterministically pick a vector that is guaranteed to be non-parallel to the given one?

Tags: vectors, cross-product

I have a unit vector $u = (x1, y1, z1)$ in $R^3$, given $(x1, y1, z1)$ are known rational numbers.

I need to deterministically pick a unit vector $v = (x2, y2, z2)$, such that $v$ and $u$ are not parallel, so ||${\bf u} \times {\bf v}$|| $\neq 0$.

$x2, y2, z2$ values can likely be derived from $x1, y1, z1$, but I can't figure out how exactly.

Comment: Just add $1$ to any coordinate (such that not all the other coordinates are $0$).

Comment: Just take (x1+1, y1, z1)? if they were parallel, one would have to be a multiple of the other.

Comment: I tried +1 approach. But to what coordinate?

Consider:
u = $(0, 1, 0)$. If I add +1 to the second coordinate and make it a unit vector again nothing will change.

Comment: "deterministically" in my case means that the solution should work in all cases for any valid $(x,y,z)$

Comment: Well a random vector will be parallel with probability zero so while not deterministic in the strict sense you can use a pseudorandom process to get it done.

Comment: Yep, random was something I considered as well.

I was still hoping there was an elegant way to effectively find one of the perpendicular vectors to the given vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z1=\pm 1$, then the unit vector is completely determined, $u=(0, 0,\pm 1)$, so you can take $v=(0, \pm 1,0)$ for example. Note that this is an equivalence, $|z1|
=1 \Longleftrightarrow x1=y1=0$

If $z1 \neq \pm 1$ then take $v=(-y1, x1, z1) $. The $z$ coordinate in the cross product is $x1^2 +y1^2$ which is different from zero.

Comment: I tried "shifting" coordinates to the right, so $v = (y1,z1,x1)$, but it never occurred to me that I can play with signs as well.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer you accepted, your notion of “deterministic” allows conditional evaluation. In that case, for any vector $\mathbf v = (x,y,z)\ne0$, the vectors $(0,z,-y)$, $(-z,0,x)$ and $(y,-x,0)$ (which are the cross products of $\mathbf v$ with the standard basis vectors) are all orthogonal to $\mathbf v$. At least two of them are nonzero: choose one. You can make this choice deterministic by always taking, say $(0,z,-y)$ unless that is zero, in which case take $(-z,0,x)$.

Comment: Ideally this would be solved without conditionals. Though I failed to find any solutions that would be just a combination of math operations (w/o conditionals)

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

Unless $x1=y1=z1$, the permuted vector $(y1, z1, x1)$ is guaranteed to not be parallel to $(x1, y1, z1)$.

Intuitively this is achieved by rotating $u$ 90° in the x-axis and then 90° in the y-axis.

In 3D the rotation matrices are:

$\begin{alignat}{1}
R_x(\theta) &= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos \theta &  -\sin \theta \\[3pt]
0 & \sin \theta  &  \cos \theta \\[3pt]
\end{bmatrix} \\[6pt]
R_y(\theta) &= \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & 0 & \sin \theta \\[3pt]
0 & 1 & 0 \\[3pt]
-\sin \theta & 0 & \cos \theta \\
\end{bmatrix} \\[6pt]
R_z(\theta) &= \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta & 0 \\[3pt]
\sin \theta &   \cos \theta & 0\\[3pt]
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{alignat}$

The resulting rotation is

$\begin{alignat}{1}
R_x(\theta) &= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\[3pt]
0 & 1 & 0 \\[3pt]
\end{bmatrix} \\[6pt]
\end{alignat}$

This has eigenvector $(1, 1, 1)$ and so only vectors with $x1=y1=z1$ will end up parallel (or antiparallel) to themselves under this transformation.

In the case where $x1=y1=z1$, you can just use $(-x1, y1, z1)$.

**Option 2:**

Convert to spherical coordinates, and then just add $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to either of the angles, say $\theta$.

Comment: That doesn't work if z = x = y?

Comment: Good point. The result is also a rotation and so there will be an invariant line in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which in this case is the line x=y=z (eigenvector is $[1, 1, 1]$.

This case is easily identified. Have changed the answer.